# figure headings on every page of list of figures

Tags: floats

I am writing my dissertation and I have lots of figures. I have FIGURE heading only on the first page of list of figures. How can you make FIGURE heading appear on every page of list of figures? Any help would be appreciated. I used the following to crate list of figures.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                           LIST OF FIGURES
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}  

\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\center\normalfont\MakeUppercase}

\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{-12pt} %% Positions the LOF title vertically to match the chapter titles
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitleskip}{12pt}


\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{%
%\\[4em]\mbox{}\hspace{2pt}FIGURE\hfill{\normalfont Page}\vskip\baselineskip} %original
\\[4em]\mbox{}\hspace{2pt}FIGURE\hfill{\normalfont Page}}

\begingroup

\begin{center}
\begin{singlespace}

% These values make the lot table entries appear double spaced between.
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0.4cm}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.30cm}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{0.30cm}
\setlength{\cftbeforefigskip}{0.4cm}
\setlength{\cftbeforetabskip}{0.4cm}

\listoffigures

\end{singlespace}
\end{center}

\pagebreak{}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what document class you're using, [here's what I'm using](http://trac.cae.tntech.edu/ttuthesis/browser/trunk/ttuthesis.cls?rev=81#L527) with `memoir` to put "Figure" in the upper left over the LoF entries, and "Page" in the upper right over the LoF entries (but below the actual page number).

```
\makepagestyle{lof}
\makeoddhead{lof}{\figurename}{}{\enlargethispage{-3\onelineskip}\normalfont\thepage\par\vspace{\onelineskip}Page}
\makeevenhead{lof}{\figurename}{}{\enlargethispage{-3\onelineskip}\normalfont\thepage\par\vspace{\onelineskip}Page}
\makeoddfoot{lof}{}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{lof}{}{}{}
```

You may be able to just use `\pagestyle{lof}` right before the `\listoffigures` command to make this work. If not, see the page I linked for my modifications to `\afterloftitle`.